# Django - doesn`t make the migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, data-migration

In Django, after I created a model, in cmd I runned: "python manage.py makemigrations" and returned that:
Migrations for 'hello':
hello\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Article
hello is the name of app. And after I runned: "python manage.py migrate" returned:
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, hello, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

And when I try to introduce a field in that model appear:
OperationalError at /admin/hello/article/add/
no such table: hello_article

I tried to delete all migrations and I created again the model and the  result was the same. How fix this?

Comment: Try `python manage.py makemigrations hello`. If it doesn't work try deleting the migrations folders along with the database if it doesn't contain needed information.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `db.sqlite3` file and redoing the migrations?- migrations are actually stored in a table in the db, so even if you change migration 0001 it won't make any changes if you rerun migrate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask], your question lacks a [mre]. Do you perhaps have a custom database router? Perhaps you run these commands on some containers or a service like Heroku? The description you give alone won't reproduce the problem you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try deleting migration files in migration folder and then delete `db.sqlite3` since model tables are stored in the database. Now run `python manage.py makemigrations` and finally run `python manage.py migrate`